# How to assign two IP address to single virtual machine in Azure

Tags: azure, ubuntu, ip-address, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I installed a software called Postal on my azure virtual machine, now I have 1 public IP address but the application requires an another IP so that it can enable fast_server and use that new IP to track all links.

I tried adding new ip by

1. Open Network Interface of that Virtual Machine
2. Click on IP   Configuration
3. Click on Add button and add that IP as secondary

I have got the secondary IP but It's not properly working or responding.

Do I have to enable any inbound rule for that IP?

Answer (score 2):

After associating a Public address resource to a new IP configuration or an existing IP configuration, you still **need to add the private IP addresses to your VM OS**.

> Review the new IP configuration. Even though a private IP address
>   wasn't explicitly assigned, one was automatically assigned to the IP
>   configuration, because all IP configurations must have a private IP
>   address.

SSH your Azure Linux VM and Complete the following steps for your VM operating system (Ubuntu):

1. Make sure you are the root user. If you are not, enter the following command:`sudo -i`
2. Update the configuration file of the network interface (assuming ‘eth0’).

   Keep the existing line item for dhcp. The primary IP address remains configured as it was previously.

   Add a configuration for an additional static IP address with the following commands:
   `cd /etc/network/interfaces.d/
   ls`

   You should see a `.cfg` file
3. Open the file. You should see the following lines at the end of the file 
   `auto eth0 
   iface eth0 inet dhcp`
4. Add the following lines after the lines that exist in this file:
   `iface eth0 inet static 
   address <your private IP address here> 
   netmask <your subnet mask>`

**NOTE:Add each of the secondary private IP addresses to the NIC with the same subnet specified for the primary IP address.**

5. Save the file by using the following command:`:wq`
6. Reset the network interface with the following command:`sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`

**Important**

**Run both ifdown and ifup in the same line if using a remote connection.**

7. Verify the IP address is added to the network interface with the following command:`ip addr list eth0`

   You should see the IP address you added as part of the list.

You can see more details about how to Assign multiple IP addresses to virtual machines using the Azure portal in [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal).  Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: How do i find the subnet? In azure network interface it is written as "moz-vnet/default" and public ip of new ip is 52.237.75.84 and private ip is 10.0.0.5. What to do next of these?

Comment: Hi, @ Sagar Singh. Go to azure portal > Select your VM > Networking > Virtual network/subnet  ; Also if the your primary private ip is 10.0.0.4 or 10.0.0.x, they are in same subnet. Next: SSH your Ubuntu VM  and complete the steps in my answer.

Comment: @SagarSingh, You can also follow the document to do it step by step. I test it and it worked for me .If this answer is helpful to you, please mark it as answer so that we can help more  communities . Thanks!

Comment: I dont' get it. We have eth0 at dhcp and immediately documentation says to put eth0 with inet static. What about eth1, since adding another interface is actually a question. Anyways, official documentation is misleading and doesn't cover the topic to a full extent. I will keep on googling... =)

Comment: I agree with @MaximV.Pavlov. Also Azure docs does just not work.